# Android: send post params, file, and text in one Http Post Request

Tags: android, http, post

I do not have a strong knowledge of how POST request looks like and how servers parse them, and google didn't gave much answers, that is why I'm posting this question here.

I have Android application, and user is able to send Http Post request to server,
he able to add post parameters, add some text to body, and attach file (This is normal case when user want to put everything in one request, right ?)

So my **FIRST** question is, how request will looks like ?

1) as I know post parameters usually located in body

2) my content type I thing should be

> multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C

So finnaly I thing http request will loke like this:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.0.1:3333 Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PostParameters"

key=value&key=value

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Message"

Some text could be here

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

File data, file data, file data
```

Is that correct ???

And my **SECOND** question is how to implement that on android ?

I see that everyone used MultipartEntity, but it requires additional open source libs, but my client don't want to use open source libs...so I have to implement that by myself.

So i believe I have to put this body in one big string, is that normal or is there better solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what I use in my apps:

**In my ServerController.class:**

**AsyncTask to POST/GET calls**

```
private final int GET = 0;
private final int POST = 1;

private class ServerRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private URL requestUrl;
    private int request_type;
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    private JSONObject json_parameters;
    private boolean showDialog;

    public ServerRequestTask(URL requestUrl, int request_type, Map<String, String> parameters, boolean showDialog) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.request_type = request_type;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.showDialog = showDialog;
    }

    public ServerRequestTask(URL requestUrl, int request_type, JSONObject json_parameters, boolean showDialog) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.request_type = request_type;
        this.json_parameters = json_parameters;
        this.showDialog = showDialog;
    }

    public String doGetRequest(URL requestUrl) {
        String responseString = null;

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpGet = null;

        if(connectedToInternet()) {
            try {

                if(parameters != null) {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = convertParameters(parameters);
                    requestUrl = new URL(requestUrl.toString() + "?" + URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                }

                httpGet = new HttpGet(requestUrl.toURI());

                HttpResponse response = null;

                response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response
                        .getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    public String doPostRequest(URL requestUrl) {
        String responseString = null;

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = null;

        if(connectedToInternet()) {
            try {
                httpPost = new HttpPost(requestUrl.toString());
                if(json_parameters != null) {
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                }

                if(parameters != null && json_parameters == null) {
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = convertParameters(parameters);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                } else if (json_parameters != null) {
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json_parameters.toString(), "utf-8");
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                }

                HttpResponse response = null;

                response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response
                        .getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(showDialog) progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        switch (request_type) {
        case GET:
            requestResult = doGetRequest(requestUrl);
            break;
        case POST:
            requestResult = doPostRequest(requestUrl);
            break;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(showDialog) progressDialog.dismiss(); 

        if (onResultReadyListener != null) {
            onResultReadyListener.onResultReady();
        }
    }
}

private OnRequestResultReadyListener onResultReadyListener;
```

**Interface for callbacks**

```
public interface OnRequestResultReadyListener {
public void onResultReady();
}
```

**Request example:**

```
public void getItemsList() {
    if(connectedToInternet()) {
        try {
            URL requestUrl = new URL(
                    Constants.ITEMS_LIST_API_URL 
                    ); 

            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("auth_token", "1234567ABC");

            itemsListApiTask = new ServerRequestTask(requestUrl, GET, parameters, true);
            itemsListApiTask.execute();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //Handle errors here
    }
}
```

The idea is that you can put whatever you want into HashMap, files or text. Also you can put JSON instead of HashMap:

```
public void postComment(String comment, int rating) {
    if(connectedToInternet()) {
        try {
            URL requestUrl = new URL(
                    Constants.ADD_COMMENT_API_URL); 

            JSONObject jsonComments = new JSONObject();
            jsonComments.put("comment", comment);
            jsonComments.put("rating", rating + "");

            postCommentApiTask = new ServerRequestTask(requestUrl, POST, jsonComments, false);
            postCommentApiTask.execute();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```